# Двойная сортировка

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

У меня есть двумерный массив в PHP. В первом измерении у меня идет ID участника, во втором его данные: 'acc'-количество решенных задач и 'point'-баллы.

Мне нужно отсортировать массив так, чтобы сначала было отсортировано по 'acc' по убыванию, а потом по 'point' тоже по убыванию.

**Пример:
Вход:**

```
$users = array(
1=>array(
   'acc'=> 5,
   'point'=> 385 
),
2=>array(
   'acc'=> 5,
   'point'=> 564
),
3=>array(
   'acc'=> 4,
   'point'=> 225
),
4=>array(
   'acc'=> 8,
   'point'=> 850
)
);
```

Выход:

```
$users = array(
4=>array(
   'acc'=> 8,
   'point'=> 850
),
2=>array(
   'acc'=> 5, 
   'point'=> 564
),
1=>array(
   'acc'=> 5,
   'point'=> 385 
),
3=>array(
   'acc'=> 4,
   'point'=> 225
)
);
```

Я думаю, что суть ясна.

Буду очень благодарен, потому что у меня олимпиада через 2 недели, а эту вещь я реализовать не смогу.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`usort()`](http://ru.php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php)

> Эта функция сортирует элементы массива, используя для сравнения значений callback-функцию, предоставленную пользователем. Используйте эту функцию, если вам нужно отсортировать массив по какому-нибудь необычному признаку.

Пример функции для сортировки по нескольким полям есть в комментарии [Gok6tm от 13-Sep-2011 01:09](http://ru.php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php#105764)

Comment: Двухмерные тоже сортирует?

Comment: Как напишите callback-функцию, так и отсортирует. Примеров по ссылке выше более чем достаточно.

Answer (score 2):

```
    function mysortfunc($a, $b) {

    if ($a['acc']>$b['acc']) { return -1; }

    if ($a['acc']<$b['acc']) { return 1; }

    if ($a['acc']==$b['acc']) {
        if ($a['point']==$b['point']) return 0; 
        return ($a['point']>$b['point']) ? -1 : 1; 
    }

}
usort($users, 'mysortfunc');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function sort_function($a, $b){
    if($a['acc'] != $b['acc'])
        return $a['point'] < $b['point'];
    else return $a['acc'] < $b['acc'];
}
usort($users, 'sort_function');
```

uasort($users, 'sort_function'); - если нужно сохранить ключи

Answer (score 0):

```
    /**
 * функция сортировки массива по 1 полю или N полей  от большего к меньшему
 *
 * @param string|array $keys
 *
 * @return int
 */
function sortFuncMaxToMin($keys)
{
    //если сортировка по нескольким полям
    if (is_array($keys))
    {
        return function ($a, $b) use ($keys)
        {
            foreach ($keys as $k) {
                if ($a[$k] != $b[$k]) {
                    return ($a[$k] < $b[$k]) ? 1 : -1;
                }
            }

            return 0;
        };
    }
    //если сортировка по одному полю
    else
    {
        return function ($a, $b) use ($keys)
        {
            if ($a[$keys] == $b[$keys]) {
                return 0;
            }
            return ($a[$keys] < $b[$keys]) ? 1 : -1;
        };
    }
}
```

```
usort($array, sortFuncMaxToMin($sortFields));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
usort($products, function ($a, $b) {

    if($a['acc'] != $b['acc'])
        return $a > $b ? 1 : -1;

    return $a['point'] > $b['point'];
});
```

с сохранением ключей:

```
uasort($products, function ($a, $b) {

    if($a['acc'] != $b['acc'])
        return $a > $b ? 1 : -1;

    return $a['point'] > $b['point'];
});
```